# Is there a phrase for the night before a weekday?

Tags: time

Sometimes I hear people say "I don't go out late on weeknights" when they mean Sunday through Thursday nights. Other times "weeknights" refers to Monday through Friday nights. Is there a less ambiguous way to say the former?

Answer (score 3):

"school night" accomplishes this well, but also carries the unwanted/inaccurate connotation of being in school (or having children who are in school).

Comment: "School night" is also used idiomatically to mean nights before someone has school the next day.  At least it is idiomatic and understood as such by people of my age and region (old, US Midwest) who are clearly past school age. :-)

Comment: I'd add that *school night* is a common expression among my peers (middle-aged British) to refer to any night from Sunday to Thursday.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *[worknight](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worknight)* (or *work night*):

> An evening before a day one has to work; a school night for someone
>   who works rather than goes to school; typically the evenings of Sunday
>   to Thursday.

So someone could say, "I don't stay out late on worknights" to refer to the evenings before a workday.